# making query more efficient when there is a millions of row

Tags: query-performance, mysql-workbench, query-timeout

My table consists of the following columns:

job_id,
event_type,
timestamp,
client_type,
role_type,

Every job_id has record of which event_type (example login, edit, delete) , what timestamp, which role did the event (system, master, agent) and which client it happened.

My query is that I want to find the list of job_id that DO NOT have a login event  BUT have a DELETE event and acted by the system

I tried a simple query using only one condition (have a loggedin event), but the DB times out/ lost connection. Is there anything I could do?

```
SELECT 
    job_id
FROM
    table.events
WHERE
    wa_id NOT IN (SELECT 
            wa_id
        FROM
            table.events
        WHERE
            event_type = 'LoggedIn' 
            )
        AND role_type = 'MASTER'
        AND YEAR(timestamp) = '2023'
        AND platform_id = '1';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is probably executing some unnecessary loop on millions of records millions of times.
Indexes could help but only if they are very selective.

A simpler way, that does require just two scans of the table is using an EXCEPT compound statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT job_id
FROM table.events
WHERE 
  event_type = 'Delete' 
  AND role_type = 'MASTER'
  AND YEAR(timestamp) = '2023'
  AND platform_id = '1'
EXCEPT 
SELECT DISTINCT job_id
FROM table.events
WHERE 
  event_type = 'LoggedIn' 
  AND role_type = 'MASTER'
  AND YEAR(timestamp) = '2023'
  AND platform_id = '1';
```

Another way, which requires a single table scan and uses filtered aggregate funcions, is this:

```
SELECT job_id
FROM table.events
WHERE 
  event_type = 'Delete' or event_type = 'LoggedIn'
  AND role_type = 'MASTER'
  AND YEAR(timestamp) = '2023'
  AND platform_id = '1'
GROUP BY job_id
HAVING count(case when event_type = 'Delete' then 1 end) > 0
   AND count(case when event_type = 'LoggedIn' then 1 end) = 0
```

Comment: thanks, I tried and the DB still lost connection. I think I might be having luck with indexes instead?